# Phonegap error on loading an external url?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, cordova

I am trying to load an external url on my iOS phonegap application.

I am using this on my ***index.html*** :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>window.open Example</title>

        <script src="cordova-2.1.0.js"></script>
        <script src="js/plugins/PushNotification.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

            // Wait for Cordova to load
            //
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

            // Cordova is ready
            //
            function onDeviceReady() {
                // external url
                var ref = window.open(encodeURI('http://apache.org'), '_blank', 'location=yes');
                // relative document
                ref = window.open('next.html', '_self');
            }

            </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

However i get the error :

```
Failed to load webpage with error: The requested URL was not found on this server.
```

** I did turn the `OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView` in the cordoba.plist to yes.

Any idea??

Comment: did you also add that URL to the whitelist? (or *)?

Comment: there is a * there. The thing is that i download a sample code from a tutorial and i was using cordova 2.1.0 . When i put my code on 2.5.0 i still get the error but the page loads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have next.html in your www folder? Your code is trying to load apache.org and without waiting for it to load, its trying to load next.html. If next.html is not present in the www folder, it will give this error.